# EXCEL Formula in master sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, excel-indirect

I want to be able to enter a formula in a "master sheet". That formula when called will be executed on the sheet in which the formula was called from.

Example:

```
Sheet 1 (master sheet)
Col A    Col B
ABC      A1 
DEF      A2xA2
GHI      A3-A1 * .05
JKL      A4+A1

Sheet 2
Col A    Col B     Col C
5        DEF       
10       ABC
15       GHI
20       JKL
```

So what I want to happen is whatever I type into Col B on Sheet2 to executes the formulas on Sheet 1 (Master Sheet) relative to the corresponding columns on Sheet 2. So  in the example above, Line 1 of Sheet 2 for Col C would be 25. I was trying a mixture of `VLOOKUP` and `INDIRECT`. It works fine if it is just the cell reference such as ABC on Sheet1. If I enter any of the others it bombs out. Since `VLOOKUP` works fine, is there anything that can "execute" the formula or evaluate the formula? Or how to get indirect to work when more than just a straight cell reference.

I am not interested in a VBA solution, I want to use straight excel functions.

Comment: `INDIRECT` function use a `Cell Reference` not an arithmetic function. Check [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261)

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using VBA because you can create a UDF in a module that calls Excel's Evaluate function, which is unavailable from worksheets:

```
Function Eval(ByVal r As Range)
    Application.Volatile True
    Eval = Evaluate(r.Value)
End Function
```

Then if you have SUM($A$1:$A$10) as text in cell C1 for example, to execute that text as a formula in a different cell all you need to do is enter:

```
=Eval(C1)
```

If you really must avoid VBA the Evaluate function is available when defining names. So with the above example of having SUM($A$1:$A$10) in C1 you could define a new name called SumCol that refers to the following:

```
=Evaluate($C$1)
```

And then you can put SumCol into a cell:

```
=SumCol
```

But I imagine defining a bunch of names like this would become tedious.